# pandas print out row with loc

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe` that upon transposing  with `print(df.T)` prints out:

```
index_label    Col1    Col2    Col3    ....  # Goes on for 25 columns
date_value1     v1      v1     v1      ....  # Max of 5 rows
date_value2     v2      v2     v2      ....
date_value3     v3      v3     v3      ....
date_value4     v4      v4     v4      ....
date_value5     v5      v5     v5      ....
```

I tried the below code to retrieve the row that I am interested in:

```
if my_date == 'date_value1':
    print(df.T.loc[my_date])
```

This gives the result of:

```
index_label
Col1        v1
Col2        v1
Col3        v1
....
Name: date_value1, dtype: object
```

My question is; How do I get it to just print out in the same format, but just of my desired `date_value`?  IE:

```
index_label    Col1    Col2    Col3    ....
date_value1     v1      v1     v1      ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need add `[]` for return `DataFrame` and then is possible transpose:

```
if my_date == 'date_value1':
    print(df.T.loc[[my_date]])
```

Or:

```
if (my_date == 'date_value1'):
    print(df[[my_date]].T)
```

Sample:

```
print (df)
index_label date_value1 date_value2 date_value3 date_value4 date_value5
Col1                 v1          v2          v3          v4          v5
Col2                 v1          v2          v3          v4          v5
Col3                 v1          v2          v3          v4          v5

my_date = 'date_value1'
if (my_date == 'date_value1'):
    print(df[[my_date]].T)

            Col1 Col2 Col3
index_label               
date_value1   v1   v1   v1
```

And thank you for better explanation, [piRSquared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43614196/pandas-print-out-row-with-loc#comment74277648_43614245):

> **df.loc[stuff]** the brackets here belong to **loc** and **stuff** is what it will get. If **stuff** is a scalar, you get a **pd.Series**. If **stuff** is a **list** or **array** then you get a **pd.DataFrame**.

Comment: This is interesting @jezrael. Could you please share with me more why I had to put it between `[[]]`?

Comment: `df.loc[stuff]`  the brackets here belong to `loc` and `stuff` is what it will get.  If `stuff` is a scalar, you get a `pd.Series`.  If `stuff` is a `list` or `array` then you get a `pd.DataFrame`

Comment: Ah. Thanks for the explanation @piRSquared :)